# Apache returns with default virtualhost after a while and only for some virtualhosts

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, httpd

**The incipit:** I had an httpd installation on a CentOS6 that worked good for years with lot of virtualhosts configured on (it is configured as a reverse proxy for lot of websites). Recently I upgraded my machine to CentOS8 and the httpd installation to 2.4.37

I used my old configuration files, just changing few obsolete directives. The service starts well and all my virtualhosts act as expected.

**The problem:** Sometimes (usually twice a week) one of my virtualhosts at random stops working, httpd just stops to recognize it returning the default virtualhost instead of it. The other virtualhosts keep working good.

With a service restart (**EDIT:** but not with a service reload) the bungled virtualhost come back to normality.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:**
I add the configuration of a virtualhost that had the problem last week:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.dm
ServerName mydomain.dm
ServerAlias www.mydomain.dm
ServerAlias mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.dm_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/mydomain.dm_access_log" combined

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.dm%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        #################
        # ERRORS
        #################
        ProxyPass        /errorpages/ !

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.50.181:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.50.181:8080/
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I've some generic directives:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
ServerTokens Prod
KeepAlive On
```

Thank you so much

Comment: There is no way to say anything about it without seeing the configuration.

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider thank you for helping. The configuration has too many virtualhosts and it is impossible to show it here. But I can show the configuration of the last problematic virtualhost and the generic directives. I add by editing the main question.

Comment: +1 just for "incipit".

Comment: Hi @anx, thank you for your answer. I've 88 vhosts on that server, organized in 20 *.conf files. No errors at startup, I spent lot of time looking for an error log but nothing.

Comment: After months of tuning we have a step, the logrotate demon has a config which reloads the apache after the log rotation. It run daily (/etc/cron.daily/httpd). We substituted the daily script with a weekly cron. This lowered the frequency but not solved the problem.

Comment: After some testing it seems that replacing the "service httpd reload" with "apachectl graceful" do the job correctly... I'm going to replace it in the logrotate script too.

Answer (score 0):

After two years of troubleshooting I've the answer, I post it for the record and because nobody in the world will suffer this pain in the future.

Apache have a daily cron running logrotate (/etc/cron.daily/httpd) and doing a log packing and then a service restart/reload.
During the restart/reload the apache service will do a reverse lookup of its IP.
The company's MS DNS server has a reverse lookup zone where IPs can be translated with names. If multiple name are recorded for an IP a round robin give just one of them.

```
# nslookup 192.168.50.5 192.168.50.1
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = www.mydomain.dm
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = www.mydomain.com
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = mydomain.com
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = service1.com
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = service2.com
5.50.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = service3.com
```

I had a forgotten default configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-default with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If a VirtualHost has no ServerName option then apache try a reverse lookup in order to know the machine name, in my case rounding the reverse lookup zones and picking up a service name randomly. So the default configuration overlaps the good one.

This behaviour is described there:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/dns-caveats.html

**Conclusion**: if you have this problem just check your VirtualHosts configuration and DNS reverse lookup zone.